# Cordova/PhoneGap: Include Directory in the project

Tags: cordova, import, include, directory, project

I'd like to include/import a directory in the cordova Project in order to be able to use some scripts of this directory.
Does it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible, simply by adding correct path name

Comment: Yes but the absolute path of the directory in the PC is different of the path in Android.
To be clear, I have the cordova project and another directory (to include) with a path like C:/stuff/stuff/theDirectory. But the problem is in Android, it doesn't reconize this path...

Comment: No, you can't include/import files from outside www folder, but you can copy/paste them inside www folder to use them

Comment: It's a bad news. I can't copy/paste this directory inside www because I use it in another place. Is it possible to create a reference of this directory with a tool (or with Windows)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible

I always include a *"Scripts"* directory within my project and include all my java-script files in this directory. You will need to reference your script files from your HTML page in the header section of the HTML:

```
<head>
     <script>
     <script src="Scripts/linq.min.js"></script>
     </script>
    <title>Project Title</title>
</head>
```

Additionally the input from Gabriel and jcesarmobile is correct but as far as I'm aware you can reference files outside of the www directory you will just need to reference the root path(in the directory tree) but I stand to be corrected.

```
<script src="../Testing/Examples.js"></script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work because Cordova transform the directory www to a directory something like _file:///android_asset/stuff_. So it seems we can't access to the parent directory.

Comment: True I think even if you reference the file like this it will still give you problems:

`/// <reference path="C:\Users\User\Documents\svn_versions\Form Mobi\FormValue\Project.Mobile\Project/Test.js" />`


If you are on mac you can add symlinks to the files you require and keep the symlinks in the www folder that may work as you require:

http://www.tricedesigns.com/2012/02/16/linked-source-files-across-phonegap-projects-on-osx/